Human Tracking вместе с YOLOv8
Абстрактно
Изображение с камеры передаётся в нейросеть YOLOv8, которая распознаёт людей, но трекинг работает плохо, потому что у людей постоянно меняются ID.
Мне нужно повысить качество трекинга людей.
Что я уже сделал
Я использую DeepSort + Torchreid, так как я прочитал, что их назначение - это трекать людей.
Сейчас мне нужно настроить Deepsort для правильного трекинга. Проблема в том, что у Deepsort есть множество параметров, которые я не знаю как настроить.
Я уже прочитал множество статей, в которых написано, что значит каждый из параметров, но всё что мне приходилось читать - это поверхностное абстрактное описание того, что нужно делать. Найти реальный опыт людей, которые сталкивались с этой проблемой мне не удаётся.
Условия
Камера видеонаблюдения находится в помещении
В помещении бывает разное количество человек от 1 до 20
Люди могут загораживать друг друга
Проблема
Не могу настроить Deepsort для оптимальной работы. Как это сделать или найти источники?
